# Combining >100 xlsx files, issue with POSIX date format due to differing columns in files

Tags: r, lapply

Relatively new to all this and would appreciate some help:

I am seeking to combine >100 xlsx files in R. They have mostly similar columns, so I am later using an rbind.fill once I have them in a list. However, I am having difficulty combining a list to one large data frame due to a date formatting issue. I am stuck at the following error:

```r
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Here is my code so far:

```r
# Reading the list of files in my folder
file_list <- list.files(path="data/")

# reading the data into a list
library(readxl)

All <- lapply(file_list,function(filename){
    print(paste("Merging",filename,sep = " "))
    read_xlsx(filename)
    })

# Merge to one dataframe
df <- do.call(rbind.fill, All)
```

This is where I receive the error. I think it is because in some files, the dates columns have varying formats.

Question: Is there a way to `lapply` function (or something like that) so that all the date columns from the list are in the same format? Am I missing something totally obvious here? I would be OK if there was a way to convert them to character and then back to date later, if that is a quick solution, but I am unsure how exactly to do that. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know all possible `Date` column names, then you might to something like this, *before* `rbind`:

```r
dtcols <- c("date", "Somedate", "date123")
All <- lapply(All, function(dat) {
  cols <- intersect(dtcols, names(dat))
  dat[cols] <- lapply(dat[cols], as.Date)
  dat
})
```

`as.Date` is idempotent, so safe to use if a column is already of class `Date`. If `cols` is empty (no columns found), this is still safe, doing nothing.

Depending on the source data, you might need to provide an `origin` or `format` to `as.Date`, such as

```r
  dat[cols] <- lapply(dat[cols], as.Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Comment: Thanks! I used this exact format but ended up with a different issue. I then changed only 'as.Date' in your example to as.numeric. This allowed them to rbind and I converted to date after the merge.

Comment: The method is the same, glad you were able to adapt. Yes, getting timestamps and dates uniformly from xlsx workbooks can be problematic.